Error loading Octomap using RViz2 plugin
The following error occurs when I try to add octomap in RVIZ2. I installed rviz2 plugin using "sudo apt-get install ros-humble-octomap-rviz-plugins"
Failed to load library /opt/ros/humble/lib/liboctomap_rviz_plugins.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library dlopen error: /opt/ros/humble/lib/liboctomap_rviz_plugins.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN7octomap13OcTreeStampedE, at ./src/shared_library.c:99

from their github repository, the workaround is:
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liboctomap.so ros2 run rviz2 rviz2

this will probably be fixed in the next release
